# Как в PHP с помощью DOMDocument() получить все корневые узлы?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть код:

```
$html = <<<'H'

<div>
  <p>Lorem.</p>
</div>

<pre class="...">
  <code>
    echo "Hello, World!";
  </code>
</pre>

ТЕКСТОВЫЙ КОРНЕВОЙ УЗЕЛ

<p>Hello.</p>

<table>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>

H;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("/*/*/*");
foreach($elements as $element) {
  echo $element->Что здесть прописать?, PHP_EOL;
}
```

На выходе мне необходимо получить массив из всех КОРНЕВЫХ элементов, вместе с их содержимым и всеми атрибутами (как есть): `array(<div>Содержимое</div>, <pre class="...">Содержимое</pre>, ТЕКСТОВЫЙ КОРНЕВОЙ УЗЕЛ, <table>Содержимое</table>, и т.д.);`, чтобы перебрать их.

Что нужно здесь `echo $element->Что здесть прописать?, PHP_EOL;` прописать?

Спасибо!

Comment: корневой узел он в принципе один, поэтому и корневой

Comment: вам там в принципе не нужен `xpath`. Просто загрузите документ, и переберите потомков первого уровня  в цикле

Comment: Да, но получить в массив то их как тогда? С регуляркой не хочется связываться.

Answer (score 0):

Если просто вывести на страницу

```
foreach($elements as $element) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($doc->saveHTML($element)), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Как добавить в массив - думаю, что объяснять не нужно ;)

Comment: Не получает текстовый узел